# install zenoss on ubuntu, raise No valid ZENHOME error

Tags: ubuntu, zenoss

I've added an user with name `zenoss`, and set `export ZENHOME=/usr/local/zenoss` in `~/.bashrc` under `/home/zenoss`, and when using `echo $ZENHOME`, it could show `/usr/local/zenoss`

When install zenoss, I switched to `zenoss` and then run `install.sh` under `zenoss-4.2.0/inst`, when it tries to run Tests, the error occured.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.zenoss.utils.ZenPacksTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.045 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running org.zenoss.utils.ZenossTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.71 sec
Results :

Tests in error: 
  testGetZenPack(org.zenoss.utils.ZenPacksTest): No valid ZENHOME could be found.
  testGetPackPath(org.zenoss.utils.ZenPacksTest): No valid ZENHOME could be found.
  testGetAllPacks(org.zenoss.utils.ZenPacksTest): No valid ZENHOME could be found.

Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Zenoss Core ....................................... SUCCESS [27.643s]
[INFO] Zenoss Core Utilities ............................. FAILURE [12.742s]
[INFO] Zenoss Jython Distribution ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.586s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 26 15:39:24 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) on project utils: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/zenoss/zenoss-4.2.0/inst/build/java/java/zenoss-utils/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

Comment: Make sure that `.bashrc` is properly sourced.

Comment: I find out that my setting is just okay, it may be a bug of zenoss's maven test, it should set a path to ZENHOME dynamically, but it sets a .jar file to it. I'm trying to fix that on ubuntu.

Comment: After revisiting this question, I should note that Zenoss is officially **not supported** on anything other than RHEL/CentOS 5 and 6. If you continue to have trouble, strongly consider using the supported distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Zenoss complained about:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) on project utils: There are test failures.
```

Make sure you actually have it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libsurefire-java
```

If this does not resolve the problem, look at the file it told you to look at:

```
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/zenoss/zenoss-4.2.0/inst/build/java/java/zenoss-utils/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

Comment: That error message is from sunfire, so its already installed

Comment: Read the rest of the answer.

Comment: I'm saying the first part is probably not correct. The second part though is the proper way to at least see what the problem is